# How can I make preview windows for Chrome/Chromium display window contents for minimized Chrome windows?

Tags: unity, compiz, google-chrome, chromium

If I have multiple gedit (for example) windows open, with some of them minimized, and I click on the gedit launcher icon twice, it shows previews of all gedit windows...including the minimized ones.

If I do the same with Chrome, it shows previews for all open Chrome windows, but the Chrome windows that are minimized are just white and don't show the window contents.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I created a bug report for this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072402

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug that has already been reported to dev.

You can read the bug-report here:

[Minimized Chrome causes blank windows with Unity's Super+W spread function](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156346)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is this:

1. Right-click the area to the right of tabs.
2. Use System Title Bar and Borders.

Also makes "Close" button appear on Chrome Windows in "Expose" view.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by other commenters it seems like this was a bug in 12.X
This is fixed in 13.04. running it right now and it works perfectly.